# Restrict user in google place api in 5 Km area given location lat lng

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to set google place auto complete text box, but I want the user only to see those places listed, which are in under 5 Km by set location. I don't talk about near-by search. I tried google map API, but it does not show correctly. [I used this API.](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyAU9ShujnIg3IDQxtPr7Q1qOvFVdwNmWc4&location=26.8510552,75.8029515&radius=500&input=m)

Comment: The provided link is not working

Comment: I suggest you copy/paste your API code into the question instead of posting a link to the API. This includes your personal API key, and each click of the link forces a new request, which will quickly put you over your API quota.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **LatLng Bounds** to Restrict Places usage

There is a workaround to do this , but involves a little bittle computation

Current Location  + Distance in North Direction = new LatLngBounds;

currentLocation + south Direction (possibly you have to convert km to radians)  = new SouthBounds;

and Add Bounds to widget

```
myPlaceAutoComplete.setBounds(northBounds,southBounds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Make Request like this

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=5000&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=AIzaSyB4sfadiVrHjkVPONVpLTLTwWnCaaWq6ok

For more information refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is probably because your radius is 500. Try changing it to 5000.

The [places autocomplete webservice documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) says the radius should be in meters.

**tl;dr**

Try [this link](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=AIzaSyAU9ShujnIg3IDQxtPr7Q1qOvFVdwNmWc4&location=26.8510552,75.8029515&radius=5000&input=m)